# SignalR and HTTPS invoking hub from client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR hub that - like always - works fine on my local machine under both HTTP & HTTPS.  However, when I move this up to our servers I can no longer invoke the hub from the client side via HTTPS.  HTTP still works like a charm.

Example:

```
//pseudo code...
var hub = getMyHub();
//this doesn't work on HTTPS.  HTTP comes back just fine.
hub.invoke('loadMessages').done(applyUpdate);
//this works regardless of protocol
hub.on('messageInboxUpdate',applyUpdate);
```

So basically when you invoke the hub using .invoke() it never comes back from the server when using HTTPS.  If you call the exact same code using HTTP everything works great.  I tested this on the same server with both HTTP & HTTPS.  I have verified that on HTTPS the request never actually gets into the hub C# code.

Comment: I assume that you are using a valid SSL cert?

Comment: Yes we have a valid cert.  We are behind a load balancer.  I think that has something to do with it. Thanks....

Comment: did u find any solution for this...? coz i am also facing same problem

Comment: We did manage to figure this out.  I can't remember exactly what we did.  I will look and see if I can find it.  If I do I will re-post.

Comment: any updated on this?